# Loading Box2D b2World from .Dump() file

Tags: c++, simulation, box2d

I am trying to save and load the state of b2World in order to resume a simulation at a later time, but with the states of the Collision Manager, etc being exactly maintained. What is the best way to do this (without getting into library internals, and having to use boost serialize while monitoring public/private members of every class)? Is there a way to repurpose the log file from b2World.dump function to construct the object again?

Answer (score 0):

I think parsing Dump as-is is a dead end.
First, the output of `Dump` seems to be [executable C++ code](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/95f74a46c077825478f989df6a81003ca538c2c2/testbed/tests/dump_loader.cpp):

```
        b2ChainShape chainShape;
        b2Vec2 vertices[] = {b2Vec2(-5,0), b2Vec2(5,0), b2Vec2(5,5), b2Vec2(4,1), b2Vec2(-4,1), b2Vec2(-5,5)};
        chainShape.CreateLoop(vertices, 6);

        b2FixtureDef groundFixtureDef;
        groundFixtureDef.density = 0;
        groundFixtureDef.shape = &chainShape;
```

Secondly, there is the problem of dumping floating point values with enough precision to recreate the original object.
Finally, some objects don't seem to support Dumping at all.

Some alternatives:

- Hack box2d and add your own state-preserving dumping mechanism
- Keep all box2d objects in a specific memory area and use memory snapshotting and/or checkpointing techniques to restore that memory again on load. One such library I know of is [Ken](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Etpkelly/Ken/), but I'm sure there are other implementations.